# Outlook Add in Redirect Href Tags

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

Good day,

I have an outlook add in, Its working fine. Now i have  tags inside of the taskpane.html. When i click the link want to redirect it to my default browser ( Chrome ) but outlook open a small window.

Ive tried everything from window.open and etc.

How do i achieve this?  can you give me some advice ?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. This is an issue put in our backlog. Unfortunately we donot have any timelines for fix at this point.
Internal tracking ID: 224390